# Чи може "пікнік" стати "гаївкою"

Tags: вибір-слова, іншомовні-слова

Цікавить, чи є відповідник до слова французького походження "[пікнік](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA)" ("популярна форма відпочинку, що полягає в споживанні їжі на свіжому повітрі на розстеленому килимку").

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/piknik) пропонує варіант "гаївка" як найточніший відповідник, однак в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghajivka) бачимо значення: " Українська народна обрядова пісня; веснянка", а також з коментарів на самому Словотворі можна зустріти, що це ще й "весняні танки і пісні".

Як на мене, набагато кращим був би відповідник "[маївка](http://sum.in.ua/s/majivka)" ("Відпочинок весною на лоні природи"). Однак, зазвичай це слово асоціюється у людей із Першим травням (У дореволюційній Росії — нелегальні збори робітників у день 1 Травня). Проте на Словотворі цей варіант не дуже популярний.

Отож чи справді можна замінити слово "пікнік" словом "гаївка"? І чи є ще якісь можливі варіанти?

Comment: Це запитання виглядає так, ніби воно запрошує субʼєктивні думки. З точки зору обʼєктивних, вимірюваних факторів ви усе розглянули самостійно, і тут додати нема чого. А от «можна чи не можна замінити» — це і є субʼєктивні міркування, які оффтопік.

Comment: Це питання відноситься до пошуку українського відповідника, тому я і в кінці запитав чи є ще якісь можливі варіанти, а от за те чи можна, я просто знайшов такий варіант на словотворі, але згідно до інформації в СУМі, такий варіант буде не найкращим відповідником до слова "пікнік". Можливо, хтось з користувачів знає ще якесь значення слова "гаївка", яке не наведене в СУМі.

Answer (score 1):

1. Чи можна замінити слово "пікнік" словом "гаївка"?

Звісно можна, але не бажано. Гаївка - це сакральне, духовне дійство і не варто його співтсавляти з просто відпочинком.

2. Чи є ще якісь можливі варіанти?

З Англомовної Вікіпедії -

> The concept of a picnic long retained the connotation of a meal to which everyone contributed something.
>
> Концепція пікніка тривалий час пов'язувалась із трапезою куди кожен щось приніс.

З мого досвіду воно десь так і є. Тому можна спробувати **все-з-собою**.